# Natural Intuition Behind Conditional Propositions?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

Basically I am having trouble reasoning out the truth table for conditional proposition / P implies Q / If P then Q / etc.

From my books and quick research on google no one seems to explain on what reasoning the definition was defined on, they all just basically give you the truth table and say accept it. I am capable of doing that, but I just totally fail to see how the 4 combined possibilities represent some coherent notion or idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: it's set up this way to make the rest of the math work out easier.

I assume the weirdness you find in the definition is that if you have `P -> Q`, and `P` is False, then you find it strange you don't have to handle the case.  If you continue going through your mathematical curriculum, you will find this actually lines up with the idea that from a contradiction you can prove anything.  The statement "If `P`, then `Q`" basically means "If `P` is true, then it *must* be the case that `Q` is true, but if not, then it doesn't matter what I do."  You might find it more natural to ocasionally say "`P` must be true, and then `Q` must also be true," but this corresponds to `P /\ Q`.

In some basic sense, however, it is just taken for granted, it seems to correspond to what you'd think at a high level as being implication, but there are sixteen possible logical relations (for binary connectives..). If you crank the logic, things work mechanically, it's occasionally best not to question it, as sometimes you really define truth before the high level intuition, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

`P implies Q` means

> Whenever P is true, Q must be true. However, when P is false, it doesn't tell us anything about Q.

For instance, consider `P = 'go out in the rain'` and `Q = 'you will get wet'`. This is consistent with going out in the rain and getting wet. It's also consistent with not going out in the rain and getting wet (you could take a shower instead) or staying dry (you don't touch any water inside). But it's not consistent with going out in the rain and staying dry.

The reason this isn't always intuitive is because in natural language we often use "if" to mean "if *and only if*", so `not P implies not Q` (e.g. "if you hit me, I'll hit you back"); we tell the difference by context and common sense. But boolean logic has a separate operator for this (it's simply the `=` operator).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, my explanation is clear enough and you see the same light I see. let p= I will buy you burrito today and q= you will buy me burrito tomorrow.
the truth table for p, q, if p then q

1st scenario- P and q are both true

if I buy you burrito today, therefore good sense requires you to buy me burrito tomorrow because I did good to you today, therefore you should pay back with good. Therefore IF P THEN Q IS TRUE

2nd scenario- p is true and q is false

If I buy you burrito today and you do not buy me burrito tomorrow, I believe that is wickedness, you cant pay evil for good, therefore IF P THEN Q IS FALSE

3rd scenario- p is false and q is true

If I do not buy you burrito today and you buy me burrito tomorrow, it will be so sweet of you to pay good for evil which is a good thing, you're being kind to me, therefore IF P THEN Q IS TRUE

4th scenario- p is false and q is false

If I do not buy you burrito today and you do not buy me burrito tomorrow, nothing happens, We go on with our lives, I can't accuse you for not buying for me or If I do you then your reply will surely be "an eye for an eye, a tooth for a tooth", therefore IF P THEN Q IS TRUE